# How to pass variable between 3 bash scripts which are called from Raspberry pi python script

Tags: python, bash, shell, variables

I run a python script on a Raspberry pi 3 which makes 3 calls to bash scripts sitting on my iMac (Yosemite).

The pi's python script has the following code for the 3 calls (note that this is a simplistic example... the python script has a series of IF statements that determine which calls are made and which 'phrase' parameter is sent... I am explaining this to avoid the suggestion that I group the 3 calls):

```
url = "http://10.0.1.11/cgi-bin/saysomethinghttp9a.sh"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

url = "http://10.0.1.11/cgi-bin/saysomethinghttp9.sh?phrase="
response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

url = "http://10.0.1.11/cgi-bin/saysomethinghttp9b.sh"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

There are **3 bash scripts**, on the iMac. The **first one** (*saysomethinghttp9a.sh*) captures the current output volume in a variable (***parm***) and then sets the output volume to a level of 14.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Content-type: text/html\n"

cat << junk
<html>
<head>
<title>
saying
</title>
</head>
<body>
junk
#-----------------------
currVol=$(osascript -e "get volume settings")
var1=$( echo $currVol | cut -d":" -f1 )
var2=$( echo $currVol | cut -d":" -f2 )
origVol=$( echo $var2 | cut -d"," -f1 )
parm="set volume output volume $origVol"

export parm

osascript -e "set volume output volume 14"
#-----------------------
cat << junk
</body>
</html>
junk
```

The **second one** (*saysomethinghttp9.sh*) takes the *phrase*, from the calling python script, and, using the *say* command talks the phrase. (note that for some reason when using the *say* command the volume is much greater than when playing music)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Content-type: text/html\n"

PHRASE=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*phrase=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/+/ /g"$

cat << junk
<html>
<head>
<title>
saying
</title>
</head>
<body>
junk
#-----------------------
say $PHRASE
#-----------------------
cat << junk
</body>
</html>
junk
```

The **third one** (*saysomethinghttp9b.sh*) is attempting to use the variable ***parm***, captured in the first script to reset the output volume level to what it was originally.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Content-type: text/html\n"

cat << junk
<html>
<head>
<title>
saying
</title>
</head>
<body>
junk
#-----------------------
osascript -e "$parm"
#-----------------------
cat << junk
</body>
</html>
junk
```

My issue is that I am trying to pass the variable ***parm***, created in the first script to the third script. As you can see from the code I tried to "export" the variable in the first script, but the third script doesn't see it!

Comment: Each http request is (probably) going to be handled on its own without any real connection between them.  If you wanted to pass information from one to another your best bet is probably either to return it to the caller somehow to have them pass it later, or to write it to a file that the other script could read later

Comment: I was coming to the same conclusion!! I am now reworking things to write the variable to a file for the 1st script, and then read from the file, saving to a variable for the 3rd script.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to pass a variable among several scripts would be to store the variable on a temporary file, which can be read by any other script. For example:

```
echo "$parm" > /tmp/ParmHolder
```

Then reading from it is easy:

```
cat /tmp/ParmHolder
```

In many systems, the directory /tmp/ is "cleared" at every boot, which is be a good thing in this case -- I suggest saving the temporary file on such a directory.